# How to create OData v3 service with supporting any/all filters

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I need update my OData service to third version. Now, I'm only changed old libraries with new from NuGet repository and in DataServiceConfiguration set property MaxProtocolVersion to V3. 
May be this is not enough? Somebody know, What exactly I must do for support any/all filters in my application?

When I try send request like this: 
http://expamle.com/OData.svc/Contacts?$filter=Phones/any(p: p/Number eq '111-222-333-11')

My application throwing this exception:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code>4</code>
    <message xml:lang="" />
        <innererror>
            <message>No property 'any' exists in type 'City' at position 5.</message>
            <type>System.Data.Services.DataServiceException</type>
        <stacktrace>
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseMemberAccess(Expression instance)
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ExpressionParser.ParseWhere()
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.ParseLambdaForWhere(IDataService service, RequestDescription requestDescription, Type queryElementType, String expression)
            at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestQueryParser.Where(IDataService service, RequestDescription requestDescription, Expression source, String predicate)
            at System.Data.Services.RequestQueryProcessor.ProcessFilter() at System.Data.Services.RequestQueryProcessor.ProcessQuery()
            at System.Data.Services.RequestQueryProcessor.ProcessQuery(IDataService service, RequestDescription description)
            at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ProcessRequestUri(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service, Boolean internalQuery)
            at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessIncomingRequestUri()
            at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
        </stacktrace>
    </innererror>
</error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure that you enabled any/all support in the DataServiceBehavior?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataservicebehavior.acceptanyallrequests(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you need to update your WCF Data Services to 5.0 to support v3 - you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306).

Comment: I'm already done this. In Framework libraries DataServiceProtocolVersion enum has only two values "V1" and "V2".

Comment: @IgorVenzhyk - and you modified your references in your project accordingly after installing it? Or you used the "Add service reference" functionality after installing it and restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: For testing application I'm using browser. In project all references correct

Comment: @IgorVenzhyk Is `City` an entity?

Comment: Now in references this dll:"Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Old libraries System.Data.Services, and so on I was deleted

Comment: City is a property in entity, Contact that reference to entity City

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like City is a singleton (not a collection) in which case you don't need any, something like this would work just fine:

i.e. `http://example.com/OData.svc/Contacts?$filter=City/Name eq 'New York'`

Any/All only apply to collections referenced in the $filter.

Comment: You are right about this case. I given not correct example.
Example should be this:
/Contacts?$filter=Phones/any(p: p/Number eq '111-222-333-11')